# How to add radio buttons to webpart editor?

Tags: 2010, visual-web-part

I have created a Visual Content Web Part in SharePoint 2010. I would like to add a setting in the webpart's editor that allow the user to select options from a set of radio buttons. I have tried Googling for an example on how to do this but I can't find anything with regards to using a visual web part (I did find one for a normal web part). Can anyone provide an example of how to do this or provide a link to a website that does show how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to create radio button control in webpart properties ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you see any "Toolbox" in the visual studio? If not, make it visible from the view menu.

There should be a control called "Radio button list" which you could add directly to the designer surface. Or you could modify the aspx markup to add radio buttons.

In any case, if you are familiar with .Net development, it is quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done radio buttons before but I have done checkboxes.

Create a property for each checkbox field:

```
[Category("Category"), WebDisplayName("Division"), WebBrowsable(true),
     Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
public Boolean Division
{
    get { return _Division; }
    set { _Division = value; }
}
```